# Can we use PKCE + Authorization code grant with the SSO in SPA?

Tags: oauth-2.0, google-oauth, single-sign-on, azure-ad-b2c, pkce

We are using SPA with PKCE Authorization code grant. Now we want to use SSO for login.
But application(SSO app) return Authorization code, which can not be persist in session or on cookies for the SSO system.

Answer (score 0):

This is by design.In PKCE flow you do two requests in order to get access token. First request is to get the code which you have already done and the second request will use this code to get the access token.

*To get access token from  below sample request will help*

```
POST /{tenant}/oauth2/v2.0/token HTTP/1.1
Host: https://login.microsoftonline.com
Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded

client_id=6731de76-14a6-49ae-97bc-6eba6914391e
&scope=https%3A%2F%2Fgraph.microsoft.com%2Fmail.read
&code=OAAABAAAAiL9Kn2Z27UubvWFPbm0gLWQJVzCTE9UkP3pSx1aXxUjq3n8b2JRLk4OxVXr...
&redirect_uri=http%3A%2F%2Flocalhost%2Fmyapp%2F
&grant_type=authorization_code
&code_verifier=ThisIsntRandomButItNeedsToBe43CharactersLong 
&client_secret=JqQX2PNo9bpM0uEihUPzyrh
```

Please refer [MS Document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-auth-code-flow) for more details

Comment: how can we implement sso then?